# Golang: protect source code

Tags: encryption, go

Go/Golang in general at the moment is a hard thing to search for, nor did I find what I was looking for here. I know there some level of encryption that can be done during compilation of an app in several languages. Can anyone give me a quick rundown of the security of Go source code after being compile to an exe? If it can be read, at least in part, is there anything out there to increase security of the source code?

Comment: What do you want to do? Are you afraid of other people stealing your source code?

Comment: Yes. I do not have the skill level with Go to do so yet, but I do have several ideas that I would like to market in a distributable application. Additionally, I'm wondering the security of say, hard coding db credentials.

Comment: Don't hardcode credentials, If your security model depends on assuming that your user cannot find out what your application does, you're not doing it right. There's always a way to extract these credentials from your software, regardless of the language you use.

Comment: Have an upvote. Maybe code security shouldn't be a high priority for me, though how might you handle db authentication in a distributed executable?

Comment: kwolfe: Design a security model that does not depend on anything hardcoded. Store credentials in configuration files. Give every user different credentials.

Comment: The problem with this is that you are assuming that I want to give every user an account, I might be referring to a logging db, or perhaps it is a read only db the I wish to retrieve info from, maybe stream info from.

Comment: If all users share the same authentification, why not totally drop the authentification?

Comment: I want to ensure that the connection is coming from my application.

Comment: @kwolfe Then generate API keys for the clients and hand them to them - via email/upon purchase, or alternatively implement something like OAuth that authorizes your client on first run and provides them a unique key that the application saves in a config file alongside it or in a suitable location for that operating system.

It honestly sounds like you're getting ahead of yourself though.

Comment: I am getting ahead of myself, but this is something I was curious about.

Answer (score 10):

Distribute only the binary (per platform/architecture). That's the best you can get with any language. There's *no way* how to distribute a program while being safe of reverse engineering it. Anyone telling you something different is probably just trying to sell you a "protection" scheme. No such thing really exists.

On the other hand: 99.9% of your potential users probably have no idea how to reverse engineer your program.

On the yet another hand: It's enough if 0.01 of your potential users have the ability to reverse engineer your program and you're doomed.

IOW, try to find out a business model which relies on anything else but security by obscurity. Actually, even open source code can generate profit - if the value of it is not only in having access to the source code per se.

Comment: Would stripping the debug info also be recommended? Go automatically builds with debug flags. Obviously the security gain is probably minimal, but for a commercially released executable it's probably worth it anyway (especially since, as I understand it, debug info can cause very slight performance hiccups and regardless).

Comment: @Jsor Go binaries are not designed to be stripped ATM - it's not recommended. There's been some discussion on the golang-nuts mailing list around this.

Comment: Even with go build -ldflags "-s"?